# Access iframe content from parent jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I want to access iframe content on parent jQuery.

I have add following code on parent page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MyIframe').load(function () {
        $('#MyIframe').contents().find('body').html('Hey, i`ve changed content of <body>! Yay!!!');
    });
});
```

My iframe page load from other site And it give me an error

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'

[Break On This Error]   

...f ( ( context ? context.ownerDocument || context : preferredDoc ) !== document )...
```

Comment: And the iFrame is of course showing content from the same domain ?

Answer (score 4):

The code is working if you remove the `onload` of the iframe. http://jsfiddle.net/qPFza/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myiframe').contents().find('body').html('Hey, i`ve changed content of <body>! Yay!!!');
});
```

So your issue is because the content of your iframe is not fired the onload that you have set.

See this example, the load function also not called here. http://jsfiddle.net/qPFza/1/

Now on this example that the content is from different web site, is not let you change it. http://jsfiddle.net/qPFza/2/

**If the web page and the iframe are from different sites you can not change the one from the other.**