# Selecting elements inside of an iframe's returns empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select some elements inside of an iframe, but it returns me empty array. The weird thing is that when I inspect the element with chrome's dev tools, then the selector works and selects the DOM. I load the iframe inside of that page 'http://localhost:8000/index.html' i don't know if it does matter.

This is the selector I'm using

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.loginTitle');
```

And it works only if I inspect the element first.

Comment: There is a solution `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142285/access-iframe-content-from-parent-jquery`

Comment: that didn't give me a solution. 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('iframe').contents().find('.loginTitle').html('Hey, i`ve changed content of <body>! Yay!!!');
});
m.fn.init [document, context: document]
0: document
context: document
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)